# Oracle SQL Update parent record depending on child records in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update the parent operation depending on its children. If all the child records are of 'D' operation, set the parent operation to 'D'. Otherwise, leave the parent operation as is. 
Here is my query so far. I would like help in getting rid of the hardcoded values:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET parentOperation = CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT DISTINCT childOperation
                FROM (
                    SELECT text_number
                        ,text_type
                        ,childOperation
                    FROM tableA
                    WHERE id = '1'
                        AND VERSION = 100
                    )
                ) = 'D'
            THEN 'D'
        ELSE parentOperation
        END
WHERE id = '1'
    AND version = 100;
```

Sample Data:

```
calculated_id (primary key) id  version parentOperation text_number text_type   childOperation
1_10    1   100 U   10  aa  D
1_20    1   100 U   20  bb  D
2_10    2   100 U   10  aa  D
2_20    2   100 U   20  bb  U
```

Expected Output

```
calculated_id (primary key) id  version parentOperation text_number text_type   childOperation
1_10    1   100 D   10  aa  D
1_20    1   100 D   20  bb  D
2_10    2   100 U   10  aa  D
2_20    2   100 U   20  bb  U
```

Comment: What database is this for?  Show example table inputs and output results.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I edited my initial post with the sample data

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE tableA a
SET parentOperation = 'D'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT null FROM tableA b
   WHERE (a.id, a.VERSION) = (b.id, b.VERSION) 
     AND b.childOperation <> 'D'
)
WHERE id = '1'
  AND version = 100;
```

Comment: I like your solution, kordirko.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableA p
  SET parentOperation = childOperation
 WHERE 1 = (  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT childOperation)
                FROM tableA c
               WHERE c.id = p.id 
                 AND c.version = p.version
            GROUP BY id, version
              HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT childOperation) = 1);
```